# Order by parent child relation on join mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables of categories having structure like this

```
category:- Id Name
category_detail: category_Id parent_Id
```

date is like this 
category

```
1  Laptop  
2  Mobile
3  HP
4  LG
5  Nokia
6  Sony
7  DELL
category_det
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  2
5  2
6  2
7  1

I want result like this
1 Laptop
3 HP
7 DELL
2 Mobile
4 LG
5 Nokia
6 Sony

    SELECT `Id`,`Name` FROM `category` 
    INNER JOIN category_det ON category_det.category_Id = category.Id
 COALESCE(category_det.parent_Id, category.Id),  cateory.Id
```

but this not returning as required. 
Thanks

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to determine a custom sorting parameter. If the `parent_id` value is 0, we can simply use the `category_id` value to sort upon; else the `parent_id` value. This is because the `parent_id` value for other levels is same as the `category_id` for the parent.

We will also use multiple level `Order By`, with second level ordering done using `category_id`.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  cd.category_id, 
  c.name 
FROM 
  category AS c 
JOIN category_detail AS cd ON c.id = cd.category_id  
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN cd.parent_id = 0 THEN cd.category_id 
       ELSE cd.parent_id 
  END
  , cd.category_id
```